# Overlay for QR code scanner using Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-qrcode

I want to implement QR code scanner like exact GooglePay:

[image: GooglePay overlay design]

I can implement the `AppBar` and `showModalBottomSheet`. But I still can't figure out how can I implement the overlay design widget (four different color borders in this case) for QR code scanner.

I have tried many packages but most of them are outdated or deprecated. **[qr_code_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner)** is the best package for QRView and **QROverlay** but it is "*Project in Maintenance Mode Only*" so I cannot use it.

I then tried using [mobile_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_scanner) package which is good but it won't provide overlay for Scanner.

I just want to design QR Code scanner overlay design for my flutter app.

Comment: Do you want this overlay to have any interactions with the phone camera or do you just want to have a visual square with colors and rounded corners?

Comment: I have to implement an application which scan the QR code and after that it will navigate the screen. So I have interaction with phone's camera and also want to code like visual square at center.

Comment: Take a look at the overlay [example in the mobile_scanner](https://github.com/juliansteenbakker/mobile_scanner/blob/master/example/lib/mobile_scanner_overlay.dart) package

Comment: How can I use it in my app? Will you please explain? Cause I'm newbie in Flutter.

Comment: There are many only courses for learning Flutter where you could learn on how to use libraries, create widgets, etc. Stack Overflow is primarily focused on specific programming questions and answers rather than broader discussions.

Comment: I know Stack Overflow is focused on programming questions but I just want to know you suggested me the example of mobile_scanner overlay but how can I use it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Stack`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) widget to add a new widget visually above your scanner.

Then you can write your own overlay widget and put it above scanner widget in stack like that:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    QrScannerWidget(...),
    OverlayWidget(...),
  ],
)
```